# F-1 US visa application: intended length of stay for a PhD program

Tags: visas, f1-visas

Recently, I was admitted to a PhD program in the United States and now I need to get a F-1 (student) visa.

At the moment, I am filling the DS-160 form and I am uncertain what should I put in the "Intended length of stay" field. My I-20 says that the approximate duration of the program is 6 years (2018 - 2024). Am I expected to use that number?

Comment: Yes. Do not worry about that, F1 visas are peculiar. I should know, I similarly used an F1.